# Send http request by loop synchronically - angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to send multiple `$http` request, the request is in `.service`:

```
app.service('servlet', function($http){
    var base = "http://myUrl.com" // real url is private
     //queryParams for GET request
    this.sendGet = function(queryParams){
    var promise = $http({method:'GET', url:base, params:queryParams}).then(
     (function(response){
       return response.data;     
    });
    return promise; // var promise 
  }
});
```

Calling `sendGet()` work fine and returns a `promise` but when I use it in a loop :

```
console.log($scope.items.length) // 5
for(var i =0 ; i<scope.items.length; i++){
//scope.items - query params
console.log(scope.items[i]);
  servlet.sendGet(scope.items[i]).then(function(data){
   console.log(i);
 });
};
```

the log show :

```
object{param1 : 1} //scope.items[i]
object{param2 : 2} //scope.items[i]
```

and then the `console.log(i)` - inside the servlet in the loop.

```
[4]5
```

Comment: Need to realize that the loop completes far sooner than the requests so `i` will always be maximum. Reason is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example. What exactly are you wanting to do?

Comment: call the request several times with diffrent params, the result is data from different DB's.

Comment: That part of the loop should be working...passing different `scope.items[i]` into the service call on each iteration. You will have a problem accessing correct `i` inside callback though unless you use a closure. See above link

Comment: I did not understant the how does the post is realted to my question?

Comment: The proper requests will be made. It's what you want to do with responses that you haven't specified. Read and understand that link and use `angular.forEach()` instead of `for` loop to create closure

Comment: Insert the data into a table, but it is sending only one request each time...

Comment: Need to concatenate results from each request into a scope array